# jquery, Regexp, make dynamic url

Tags: javascript, regex, url

I need a regexp help, because for me it will take a lot of time , for you  some minutes:)

I have youtube a URL :

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9_Hd8hXhg7o&feature=youtube_gdata
```

I can't add this in embed object , for embed I have to change in this URL :

```
http://www.youtube.com/v/9_Hd8hXhg7o&hl=en_US&fs=1&
```

It means, that I want to add the youtube cod in some variable, something like this

```
var url = after regexp "9_Hd8hXhg7o";

"http://www.youtube.com/v/" + url +"&hl=en_US&fs=1&";
```

thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it:

```
var url = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9_Hd8hXhg7o&feature=youtube_gdata";

var id = url.match(/(\?|&)v=(.*?)(&|$)/)[2];

var new_url = "http://www.youtube.com/v/" + id+"&hl=en_US&fs=1&";
```

This should work on pretty much every format you throw at it. This snippet looks for `?v=` or `&v=` and any characters after that until an `&` symbol or end of line, so the ID can be found from these also:

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9_Hd8hXhg7o
http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=youtube_gdata&v=9_Hd8hXhg7o
http://www.youtube.com/watch?fs=1&v=9_Hd8hXhg7o&feature=youtube_gdata&
```

Comment: Rather than checking for `&` and `?` separately, you can probably get away with just using `\Wv=(.+?)(&|$)`. In fact, you can make it even easier by using some character classes: `[?&]v=(\w+)`